# How can I simplify this boolean equation for the multiplexer a little further?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I've obtained a formula through cannonical representation, which is:

$$A\cdot \overline{B\cdot S}+A\cdot B\cdot \overline{S}+\overline{A}\cdot B\cdot S+A\cdot B \cdot S$$

And I'm trying to simplify it to:

$$( A \cdot \overline{S}) + (B \cdot S)\tag{1}$$

Following the laws [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28logic%29#Laws), I've done this:

$$A\cdot B\cdot \overline{S}+\overline{A}\cdot B\cdot S+(A\cdot B \cdot S+A\cdot \overline{B\cdot S})$$

$$A\cdot B\cdot \overline{S}+\overline{A}\cdot B\cdot S+A\cdot (BS+\overline{BS})\tag{Complementation 2}$$

$$A\cdot B\cdot \overline{S}+\overline{A}\cdot B\cdot S+A\cdot (1)\tag{Identity for ∧}$$

$$A\cdot B\cdot \overline{S}+\overline{A}\cdot B\cdot S+A$$

I'm having problem at this step, I'm not sure how to proceed, I did the following:

$$B\cdot (A\cdot \overline{S}+\overline{A}\cdot S)+A$$

Trying to obtain some insight, but from here, I have no idea on how to proceed to the form $(1)$.

Comment: Are you sure your expression starts with "$A\cdot\overline{B\cdot S}$" instead of "$A\cdot\overline B\cdot\overline S$" to begin with?

Comment: Do you really mean $A\cdot \overline{B\cdot S}$ in the first term, rather than $A\cdot\overline B\cdot \overline S$? As written, what you're starting with is not a DNF.

Comment: Your original formula is not equal to the supposed simplification. Try for instance to substitute $A=1,B=0,S=1$. That will lead to a contradiction.

Comment: I've used $A\cdot\overline{B\cdot S}$ to represent $A\cdot\overline B\cdot\overline S$. Is there a problem doing so?

Comment: In the book I'm reading ([The Elements of Computing Systems](http://www.nand2tetris.org)), they write without the `\cdot` to represent $AND$, then it's written as $A\overline{BS}$, because of this, I thought there was no problem in writing $A\cdot\overline{B\cdot S}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution, assuming I've correctly interpreted the question:
$$
AB'S' + ABS' + A'BS + ABS =
\\ A(B' + B)S' + (A' + A)BS =
\\ AS' + BS
$$
as desired.  Here, $A'$ means "not $A$".  Note that the notation $\overline{B\cdot S}$ is unclear since $(BS)' \neq B'S'$.  For a good way of making such simplifications in general, look into [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: Yep. I know about the Karnaugh maps, but I've really prefered the simplification of the formula.

Comment: One more question: Is it possible to proceed from where I was? $A\cdot B\cdot \overline{S}+\overline{A}\cdot B\cdot S+A$?

Comment: No, you made a mistake: $BS + B'S' \neq 1$

Comment: Yes. I've made the table now. I thought that I could make $BS=x$ and $\overline{BS}=\overline{x}$ and then $x+\overline{x}=1$.

Comment: Remember, $B'S' \neq (BS)'$. That's where DeMorgan's laws are useful.